# Windows Server Folder Replication

Tags: windows, iis, directory

I have two servers using MS NLB for IIS and this is working great.

I have a D:\Websites\ directory on both servers that contain the html, css, aspx, and images etc. I would like to have the D:\Websites\ directory on ServerA be replicated to D:\Websites\ on ServerB. I don't need any snyc, just a brute copy/replace from ServerA -> ServerB.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) is probably the best choice for a simple copy.

```
robocopy src dst /mir
```

Comment: Should I set this up as a scheduled task on ServerA?

Comment: Yes, unless you really want to sit there and run it manually. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Distributed File System](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/storage/dfs/default.mspx), but it's probably overkill.

We just use Robocopy + batch file + scheduled tasks to copy this from 1 server to 3 others. Robocopy is available for Server 2003 as part of the [Resource Kit tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en), or built-in to Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Seems better to be using features built into IIS, that it was designed to use, than using a bunch of extra points of failure, like Scheduled Tasks, and Scripts etc.

You could share the folder on ServerA, and then change ServerB IIS settings for the site so that the Home Directory is set to *"A share located on another computer"* - which you would then point back to the share on ServerA

If redundancy is a concern, you could move the data to a different server altogether, share it, then do as I mentioned above to both ServerA and ServerB.

Just thinking out loud!

[image]
<sub>(source: [novell.com](https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/img/18687-9.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I thought about this, but I chose robocopy since I trust a scheduled task as a point of failure more than a network file server.

Answer (score 0):

I like Super Flexible File Synchronizer for this because it has built in logging and email notification for failure.